# Error in displaying Laravel (Lumen) errors

Tags: php, lumen

I use Lumen Framework (8.3.1) (Laravel Components ^8.0).
I see following message when there's an error and I check Firefox Web developer tool's response in network tab:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException:
> include(views/exception_full.html.php): failed to open stream: No such
> file or directory in path to project
> foder\api\vendor\symfony\error-handler\ErrorRenderer\HtmlErrorRenderer.php:355

function that includes line 355 is (line 355 has the include command),

```
private function include(string $name, array $context = []): string
{
    extract($context, \EXTR_SKIP);
    ob_start();

    include is_file(\dirname(__DIR__).'/Resources/'.$name) ? \dirname(__DIR__).'/Resources/'.$name : $name;

    return trim(ob_get_clean());
}
```

I think I started getting this error after moving the project to a different location and ran `composer install`

There's also following error in php error log,

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> app_path() in Command line code:1

Comment: can u try this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=2

Comment: @MizbahAhmed thx for looking into this, this is the value in my php.ini error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_WARNING
Isn't my issue due to a missing file?